# POSTMAN is showing findByIdAndUpdate is not a function

Tags: express, post, postman, backend

[Error in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3pZK.png)

**This is my Code:**

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQd4w.png)

Server is starting successfully, without syntactical errors

tried searching for bugs, but couldnt find anything, changed name of models, tried restarting IDE and POSTMAN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the correct method name is findByIdAndUpdate as follows

```
const updatedPost = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
  post,
  { $push: { comments: savedComment._id } },
  { new: true }
)
```

you might need to capitalize the 'a' in 'and' as it is not recognized

Comment: I got the answer, i tried capital 'A' but that even didn't worked because i forgot to export Post from models, now got it, thanks